# Scaling count data that contains zeros

Tags: hypothesis-testing, count-data

Imagine that I have 40 observations in region A, and 50 observations in region B. The total size of region A in square kilometers is 50km, and the total size of region B is 40km. Within each region, each observation has a count of events that ranges from 0 (fairly frequent) to 20.

What is the best way to hypothesis test for a difference in mean events per square kilometer between region A and region B?

I've considered the following options:
1) Using a negative binomial regression with the area of each observation as a covariate.
2) Scaling the dependent variable (event counts) somehow.
3) Subsetting A and B via matching to achieve an equivalent total area on each side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a robust poisson regression with a [logarithmic offset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/41455/7071) for area? The linked example uses time, but I think the intuition carries over to space.

Answer (score 1):

If zeros are "fairly frequent" in your data, it sounds like a [zero-inflated model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model) might be appropriate. In order to account for covariates like the area, you may want to look at [zero-inflated Poisson regression](https://www.google.com/search?q=zero-inflated%20poisson%20regression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Comment: So you think that adding the area as a covariate and then modeling the over-dispersion of 0's is the best approach here? One additional option that didn't occur to me -- what about running a weighted regression with the weights determined by land area.

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing the specifics of your problem. Zero-inflated Poisson regression will allow you to model causal effects like area both on the amount of zero inflation *and* on the Poisson parameter (or only in one of the two components). Which model to use will depend on the underlying causalities of zero inflation and event count you hypothesize.

Comment: interesting discussion about zinf models here: http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/zero-inflated-models